# Post Request, Post image to local host python? Better way to host images?(python)

Tags: python, image, opencv, request, ip

I am attempting to post an image taken with OpenCV to a local page to which its url can be referenced by a Twilio application in another script. From my research, the Requests library seems like it will be useful, however, i am inexperienced and don't know much about internet protocol best practices. If someone could correct some of my mistakes and point me to some tutorials it would be greatly appreciated.

This is what the debuger says:

```
* Running on http://***.*.*.*:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
***.*.*.* - - [21/Aug/2020 15:33:56] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What I'm trying to figure out is which address should use as the reference for a twillio media url.

Post Handler:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return 'This is home page'

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def handleFileUpload():

    msg = 'failed to upload image'

    if 'image' in request.files:

        photo = request.files['image']

        if photo.filename != '':

            photo.save(os.path.join('.', photo.filename))
            msg = 'image uploaded successfully'

    return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

client

```
import socket
import pickle
import cv2
from os import path
import requests as req


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


#if (true):
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('temp.jpg', frame)
url = 'http://localhost:8000/upload'
with open('temp.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    files = {'image': f}
    r = req.post(url, files=files)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: What happens if you execute server and client? Usually questions are about problems, bugs or code that does not work as supposed to. Please edit your question and point out what is going wrong with your code

Comment: @Robert sorry, I have updated my post to reflect what I am not understanding

Comment: I still don't see any problem in what you have posted. BTW 127.0.0.1 is localhost you don't have to replace that IP with stars.

Comment: if you want to send to other computer in local network then in `requests` you need server local IP - like `192.168.0.1` - it is server IP assigned to one of its network cards (lan/cable or wifi) which you should get using `ifconfig` on server. OR using on other client computer program like [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to scan all computers in local network. Of course you can also use `requests` with different IP (192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, ...) until you get some answer from server.

Comment: In server to get data from other computers you should use IP assigned to one of its network cards (LAN/cable or WIFI) like `192.168.0.1`. Or use `0.0.0.0` to get requests from all network card. Using `127.0.0.1` in server you can get only from programs running on server.

Comment: if server/flask shows port `5000` then you have to use port `5000` in client too - but you use `8000` in client.

Comment: if you want to use your local images with external program (running somewhere in internet) then external program will have to use external IP of your server - it means IP of your Internet Provider router - which you can get with pages like https://www.myip.com/ . Sometimes problem is that  Internet Provider can blocks some ports and your server may have to use popular ports like `80` which is for HTTP server, or `8080` which is for HTTPS server.

Comment: Other problem is that some Internet Providers may change your external IP every 24h and then your whould need something like `dynamic DNS`  https://account.dyn.com/ or use `ngrok` https://ngrok.com/ and then external programs may use text address like `my_server.ngrok.io` and it will be converted to your current external IP.